# Visual Studio Auto Tabify Document Without Asking

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I work with a team where everyone's indentation settings are different. I like 2 spaces for a tab, while others like the default 4, and some like 3 (why??!). I had everyone set their documents to use tabs instead of spaces, so everyone would be happy. However, the Tabify bar pops up, constantly asking if we want to tabify the document.

[image: Tabify document dialog in code editor]

The actual logic behind this is smart in that it tabs anything that should be tabbed and leaves other whitespace alone. That's great. My problem is with the bar itself. I want it to auto tabify my documents and never ask me. We find ourselves ignoring the bar, which when code is checked into source control, looks all jacked up on other people's IDEs.

Is there a way to tell it to always tabify the document on save and never ask me?

Comment: I've noticed that it always gives you the option even if you change everything yourself. Next time you open the file, it will pop back up. There's no way to automatically get it to choose one but I believe that you can just turn that popup off.

Comment: A dev on my team saw the "Fixed" option under the configuration, but that's only hiding the dialog.